# return get datagridview cell value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to return the value contained in a datagridview cell upon clicking on the cell. can anyone please show me how to do this using vb.net?thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this sample code. The key is to use the event's `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` parameter to find the clicked cell's `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex`.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                    Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: P.S: You will probably get more answers if you actually bother to mark the answer which helped you most - Reputation is the only reward for those answering you.

Answer (score 0):

You can call from a button

```
Dim y As String = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value

If IsDBNull(y) Then

Else

TextBox1.Text = y

End If
```